# Cakephp Form create add url as query string

Tags: php, url, cakephp

When we use below method it adds url as query string

```
$this->Form->create('ProductRating',array('id'=>'validateForm'));
```

we get this `url "/products/review_reply/17?url=products%2Freview_reply%2F17"`

How to prevent adding url as query string ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried additional parameters inside? like `'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add')`. this information came from [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: can you post the complete form?

Comment: Your mentioned url seems not to match your created form.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, try to force the form type as so:

```
$this->Form->create('ProductRating',array('id'=>'validateForm', 'type' => 'post'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  echo $this->Form->create('Model', array(
        'url' => array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'review_reply'),
        'id'=>'abc',
        'type'=>'post'
    ));
```